# jQuery elevateZoom plugin - image on center

Tags: javascript, css, html

Anyone knows how to put the image on this plugin in center? Because, with small images it appears always on left top.

On github it says nothing. https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom
I probably have to find in the .js file where it creates the div or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to center my images by placing everything in a div like the one below, however it's not centering the zoom on the "inner" zoomType when using a vertical image. Example: http://brecksargent.com/j/

```
<div id="wrapper" style="text-align: center">    
<div id="yourdiv" style="display: inline-block;">
</div>
</div>
```